# Does the Entropy of the Visible Universe Decrease?

Tags: cosmology, entropy

My understanding is that the entropy in a closed system increases. However, I would also assume that the number of particles in the open system of a visible universe decreases because of accelerated expansion.

(1) What would be the entropy of the visible universe when only one particle is left? Is the entropy higher than the entropy in the visible universe today?

(2) How does the entropy of the visible universe change in time?

Comment: The entropy *of a closed system* always increases.

Comment: @fqq The visible universe is not a closed system

Comment: @fqq changed the wording a bit to make the question more clear

Comment: because of expansion, not necessarily accelerated ... I wonder what is the physical meaning of this entropy while it is tempting to imagine some law related to the expansion rate

Answer (score 0):

1. With one particle, it would be nearly impossible to convert energy into work. So the entropy would be significantly higher than the entropy of our current universe, in which energy to work conversion is possible.
2. Overall, the entropy of our universe increases in accordance to the second law of thermodynamics. The reason being that a percentage of energy released in reactions is produced as heat, which cannot be regained.

Comment: The part about one particle is wrong, depending on how you interpret "one particle". A universe containing one quantum particle has very low entropy!

Comment: The fact that with only one particle it would be nearly impossible to convert energy into work does not necessarily mean the current entropy is high, it just means the rate at which entropy changes is low.